# c# CheckBoxes and pointing at them

Tags: c#, checkbox, for-loop

I'm trying to make physics calculator or so.

I can't point loop to check if `checkBox` is checked.

I tried :

```
for (int cb = 0; cb <= 31; cb++)
{
    if(*checkBox1.checked* == true){}
}
```

What do I put in place of : `*checkbox[cb].checked*`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: We need more information. Are there many checkboxes on the form? Do they all have names? Is this a WinForms/Web Apps/WPF/SilverlightWinRT application?

Comment: use checkbox list and loop through the for each item of checkbox list wil do the trick

Comment: I am doing  WindowsFormsApplication , and using Form1:tabcontrol:page1 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use LINQ to your advantage if you are wanting to look at all the checkboxes in a control/panel/etc...

```
// Filter the controls collection for checkboxes
foreach(var cb in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()) 
{
  if(cb.checked)
  {
    // do something
  }  
}
```

If all the checkboxes you can about are in a single `Panel`, you could do something like `Panel1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()` instead so you only grab the ones you want.

Comment: They are in TabControl tabpage 1 :)

Comment: Then you should be able to do `tabpage1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()` to get a list of all the checkboxes you want, already strongly-typed for you! :)

Answer (score 2):

We need a little more information here, is checkbox a CheckBoxList?

```
for (int cb = 0; cb <= 31; cb++)
{
    CheckBox check = (CheckBox)checkbox[cb];
    if(check.Checked) { 

    }
}
```

or, if dynamic names...

```
for (int cb = 0; cb <= 31; cb++)
{
    CheckBox check = (CheckBox)Page.FindControl("checkbox" + cb);
    if(check.Checked) { 

    }
}
```

Something along those lines should do the trick for your scenario.

Comment: Actually it says :  Page does not exist in the current context. 
I am using tabcontrol. Could you suggest me something else ?